# Ficus bonsai dropping leaves and white powder

Tags: identification, diseases, tree-care, bonsai, ficus

So I bought a ficus microcarpa bonsai from the store 2 month ago and I noticed a problem since then, some leaves turn partially brown and fall while it's still wet not dry, some new growth also falls while still green, it falls at a rate of 1 leave/day.
[image: The brown leaves that fall are usually the larger ones]

The prime suspect is the white powder on the leaves, I tried washing it with distilled water but it didn't wash off.

[image: white powder that is either mold or mineral crystals]

I also checked the roots to see if the plant is root bound or has root rot but I don't think so as you can see in the picture.

[image: the soil is packed because I picked it after watering]

So basically I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, this is my first bonsai, I would appreciate the help.

more info:

It's kept indoors with humidity between 40%-60% with a temperature range of 22-27 Celsius.

The main source of light is a CFL lamp 150 watts that is kept on for 8 hours a day, the lux reaching the leaves is 3000 lux with no hotspots.

I fertilized it twice a month with 1 gram of npk 20-20-20.

I water it with tap water when the top soil is dry.

Comment: That seems to be an awful lot of roots and soil for a bonsai.

Answer (score 1):

The white powder is either pesticide residue or hard water residue from overhead watering.  It does no harm and can be removed by rubbing the leaf with a cloth.

The root ball looks fine as the roots are firm with white new growth at the tips. There is no sign of the most common issue: over watering.

The leaf drop is well known with Ficus and new plants as they adjust to the light levels. [Outdoor sunshine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6656201/figure/i2164-2591-8-4-7-f03/) can be over 10,000 lux. One hopes the grower put the plant under shade cloth for a few months to get it adjusted to a light level of ~ 3000 to 5000 lux.

The plant cannot sustain dense foliage with one CFL lamp and is thinning out.

I recommend:

- do not fertilize for at least a few months.  Fertilizer will encourage etiolation or stretching out of branches.
- water with filtered water. Tap water often contains chlorine or chloramine or both which can be detrimental in the long term
- thin the leaves and branches
- increase the light by moving next to a sunny window
- overwatering is the number one cause of indoor plant problems.  Consider a wick system.